# my phone doesn't load any picture i take with the camera

Tags: camera, photos, gallery, media-files, thumbnails

I thought there was some sort of problem with my camera but it works just fine except that it doesn't load the pictures i take with it. I take a picture and when i try to view it it turns out to be a black screen. And in the gallery it sometimes doesn't show at all. I also can't send them because it says "error loading media". And none of my photos in the gallery have a thumbnail. What can i do?
P.S. I have the 9gag app and it doesn't load any picture on it either; as in i can't view any post whatsoever. Also with instagram.

Comment: Strange, sounds like you might be missing a JPG decoder library or something.  What device and OS are you running?  Has this problem always occurred?

Comment: Do you have the camera app set to save to the SD card? If so, the problem may sit with a bad card or problems communicating with the card.

Comment: I have a lenovo running on  android *i hope that's what you're asking me* and Îmi fact, yes, i have my camera app  set to save on the SD card. Now that i think of it, this problem started the day after i changed that. So  basically every photo I took before changing the 'where to save' settings are still on my phone, but they still don't have a thumbnail. The photos I took after the settings don't show at all.